# sum of date difference of different id in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have user defined function like this:

```
create FUNCTION dbo.FormattedTimeDiff (@Date1 DATETIME, @Date2 DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiffSeconds INT = sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Date1, @Date2) )

    DECLARE @DiffHours INT = @DiffSeconds / 3600
    DECLARE @DiffMinutes INT = (@DiffSeconds - (@DiffHours * 3600)) / 60
    DECLARE @RemainderSeconds INT = @DiffSeconds % 60

    DECLARE @ReturnString VARCHAR(10)

    SET @ReturnString = RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffHours AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffMinutes AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@RemainderSeconds AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)

    RETURN @ReturnString
END
```

I try execute out put like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.vtid,
    dbo.FormattedTimeDiff(PayDate, DelDate)
FROM    
    dbo.Transaction_tbl t  
    where t.Locid = 5
```

but I am getting output like this:

```
vtid        
----------- ----------
7           00:21:42
7           01:05:30
7           00:37:43
7           NULL
8           00:00:42
8           00:07:25
7           00:25:36.
```

I want to get sum of date difference of vtid 7 and 8

Expected output:

```
vtid   
7        01:25:45
8         00:07:45
```

I tried giving group by but showing error, so where I have to made changes in my stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in that case, you need to change "*your*" function to use seconds as input parameter - not two dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormattedTimeDiffFromSeconds] (@Seconds INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiffHours INT = @Seconds / 3600
    DECLARE @DiffMinutes INT = (@Seconds - (@DiffHours * 3600)) / 60
    DECLARE @RemainderSeconds INT = @Seconds % 60

    DECLARE @ReturnString VARCHAR(10)

    SET @ReturnString = RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffHours AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffMinutes AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@RemainderSeconds AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)

    RETURN @ReturnString
END
```

and then you can do your select, sum up the time difference in seconds, and format it:

```
SELECT
    v.Vtype, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate)) as sum_min,
    dbo.FormattedTimeDiffFromSeconds(SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))),
    AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), DATEDIFF(MI, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))) as avg_min
FROM
    dbo.Transaction_tbl t 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.VType_tbl v ON t.vtid = v.vtid 
WHERE 
    t.transactID IN (24, 25) 
GROUP BY
    v.Vtype
```